# Catching product attribute update massaction event

Tags: magento, events, event-handling, product

I am trying to listen to the "catalog_product_save_before" and "catalog_product_save_after" events which are correctly triggered when I save individual product from admin interface.

But, these events are not triggered when I use the "update attributes" action for multiple product selections, from the product list grid. Is there any event which is triggered whenever a product attribute is updated ?? I know I need to write different observer function for csv upload but I need the event for grid action "Update attributes"..

Thanks in advance.

Cheers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this to work out!!

I used this event : catalog_product_attribute_update_before

This give an array with changed attributes and product ids :

```
        [attributes_data] => Array
            (
                [price_markup] => 10
            )

        [product_ids] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6
            )

        [store_id] => 0
```

Hope this helps ..

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

this might be a vague answer, I am not sure what you try to do with the attribute but maybe have a look into the Mage_Indexer module. Its bit more complex but it listens to all events or at least Magento takes care of notifying it if something is outdated or has changed.

And also if something goes funky with your data, rerunning your indexer should clean up all the data in an ideal world.

Comment: I just wanted to catch all updated products for a specific attribute and update price attribute based on it. The exact requirement was to have a % markup attribute and on editing this attribute the product price should increase by that percentage. Thanks for you help... :)